# controlling postgresql log generation

Tags: postgresql, logs

My disk space fills up daily with postgresql logs. One optimzation solution I'm pursuing is that instead of turning off logs, I should overwrite the original log file (i.e. rotate?) once it hits a certain size (say 200MB).

How do I enable such a setting in `postgresql.conf`? I'm aware that a better solution would be to backup all logs, but for now this is the one I want to pursue.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-ROTATION-AGE

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: it seems `log_rotation_size` could do the trick, but only if the new file created has the same filename as the previous one, so that it overwrites the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce your log levels; for example, turn off `log_transaction` and set `log_statement` to something above `all`. Use `pg_stat_statements` instead of relying on full statement logging. Use Munin/Cacti/collectd/similar to collect system stats rather than relying on tools like `pgbadger` for log parsing.

Use `logrotate` if you're on a Linux system and using a system PostgreSQL install. It knows how to compress then age out logs. See `/etc/logrotate.d/` .

PostgreSQL's built-in log rotation, as you have observed, is somewhat limited and really expects you'll be archiving and deleting them via a cronjob or similar. But you can do just that and use `log_rotation_size`.

You can also log to syslog. This gives you severity filtering, etc with a decent syslog like `rsyslogd`. You can make it keep `ERROR` level logs for ages, but quickly discard `INFO` and older, for example, by working alongside `logrotate`. You can even log to a remote syslog server with abundant disk space if you want to do long term archival.

There are commercial log ingestion products you can use to feed your logs in for archival and analysis too.